# BJT Circuit DC Analysis

Tags: transistors, bjt

[image: BJT Circuit with two NPN transistors]

I am trying to find the collector's current of each transistor in order to find the transconductance gm of both, but I don't know how to relate the currents of them. There's any approach? Thanks

Comment: They have to add to 1mA, and there's a hard limit on the right transistor.

Comment: What is Vs? AC or DC or both? This is an important information for finding the collector currents.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ are forward-biased
- \$V_s\$ is DC
- the transistors are physically identical (temperature, doping concentrations, \$\beta\$, etc.)

Then, we determine that (from KVL on \$Q_2\$ base-emitter junction):
\$0 - V_{BE} = V_E \$ 
 
\$V_E = -V_{BE}\$

Then, we determine that (from KVL on \$Q_1\$ base-emitter junction):
\$V_s - I_{B1}(10000) - V_{BE} = V_E = -V_{BE}\$ 
 
\$V_s - I_{B1}(10000) = 0\$ 
 
\$V_s - \frac{I_{E1}(10000)}{\beta + 1} = 0\$ 
 
\$I_{E1} = \frac{V_s(\beta + 1)}{10000}\$

Using KCL at the emitter node:
\$I_{E1} + I_{E2} = 0.001\$ 
 
\$I_{E2} = 0.001 - I_{E1} = 0.001 - \frac{V_s(\beta + 1)}{10000}\$

Conclusion:
\$g_{m1} = \frac{I_{E1}}{\alpha V_T} = \frac{V_s(\beta + 1)}{10000\alpha V_T}\$
\$g_{m2} = \frac{I_{E2}}{\alpha V_T} = \frac{0.001 - \frac{V_s(\beta + 1)}{10000}}{\alpha V_T}\$